# TabControl Padding causes hidden Controls in TabPage to re-order incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

The controls with `Handles` not yet created seem to be pushed to the bottom of their `Parent` `Control` when the `TabControl`'s `Padding` property is changed. Looking at the `.NET` source code, `Padding` makes a call to `RecreateHandle();`, which seems to have something to do with it.

Below is code that illustrates the problem. Each `checkbox` has a corresponding `label` just below it. Some of the labels are visible at the start, some are hidden. Checking the `person0` checkbox makes the `person0` label appear, but incorrectly at the bottom. Instead, the person0 label should appear just underneath the person0 checkbox, which is the order it was added to the `FlowLayoutPanel`. See screenshot.

The code provides a `bool doWorkaround` option, but there must be a better way. Forcing all the `Handles` to be created using `CreateControl()` seems not correct either.

[image: example]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3 {

public class TabControl3 : TabControl {

    private bool doWorkaround = false; // set to true to prevent the bug

    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        int h = (int) this.Font.Height;
        SetPadding(new Point(h, h)); // calling this causes the Controls to re-order incorrectly
    }

    ///<summary>Setting the padding causes the TabControl to recreate all the handles, which causes the hidden handleless controls to rearrange.</summary>
    public virtual void SetPadding(Point pt) {
        // Workaround solution: remove all controls from tab pages and then add them back after.
        int n = TabPages.Count;
        Control[][] arr = null;
        if (doWorkaround) {
            arr = new Control[n][];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                TabPage tp = TabPages[i];
                arr[i] = tp.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToArray();
                tp.Controls.Clear();
            }
        }

        this.Padding = pt; // in the .NET source code, setting Padding calls RecreateHandle()

        if (doWorkaround) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                TabPages[i].Controls.AddRange(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class CheckBox2 : CheckBox {
    public CheckBox2(String text, bool isChecked = false) : base() {
        this.Text = text;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.Checked = isChecked;
    }
}

public class Label2 : Label {
    public Label2(String text) : base() {
        this.Text = text;
        this.AutoSize = true;
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form {

    TabControl tc = new TabControl3 { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

    public MyForm() {
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 800);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        TabPage tp1 = new TabPage("Page1");

        FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel { FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        p.Controls.Add(new CheckBox2("Person0"));
        p.Controls.Add(new Label2("Person0") { Visible = false });

        p.Controls.Add(new CheckBox2("Person1", true));
        p.Controls.Add(new Label2("Person1"));

        p.Controls.Add(new CheckBox2("Person2", true));
        p.Controls.Add(new Label2("Person2"));

        p.Controls.Add(new CheckBox2("Person3"));
        p.Controls.Add(new Label2("Person3") { Visible = false });

        p.Controls.Add(new CheckBox2("Person4"));
        p.Controls.Add(new Label2("Person4") { Visible = false });

        for (int i = 0; i < p.Controls.Count; i += 2) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) p.Controls[i];
            Label lb = (Label) p.Controls[i+1];
            cb.CheckedChanged += delegate {
                bool b = cb.Checked;
                lb.Visible = b;
            };
        }

        tp1.Controls.Add(p);
        tc.TabPages.Add(tp1);

        Controls.Add(tc);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Font = SystemFonts.MenuFont; // to trigger the bug
    }
}

static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}
}
```

I tested using `.NET 3.5, 4, 4.52` and saw the same behavior in all three.

Comment: Override `OnControlAdded` of your TabControl and add `base.OnControlAdded(e); if (e.Control is  TabPage) { e.Control.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.CreateControl()); }`. Also add, in `OnFontChanged` (you could also use `OnLayout`), after `base()`, `if (!this.IsHandleCreated) return;`. Remove everything in `SetPadding()` except `this.Padding = pt;`

Comment: In OnFontChanged is probably better if you have: `var p = new Point(Font.Height, Font.Height); if (!Padding.Equals(p)) SetPadding(p);`

Comment: Btw, you could use a TableLayoutPanel instead of a FlowLayoutPanel :) (or one UserControl instead of two Controls)